# Can someone explain why printf("%s", str + str[0] - str[3]); works in C?

Tags: c, c-strings

```
char *str = "ESPA1";
printf("%s", str + str[0] - str[3]);
```

I know that the **output is 1**, but I do not understand why it is kinda possible to "cut" a part of a string like this.

Comment: Just a little pointer arithmetic, with a bit of ASCII arithmetic.

Comment: [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/) holds the key.

Comment: A string is just an address in memory where the values 'E', 'S', 'P', 'A', '1', and 0 are stored. Add to that address and it starts in the middle of the string. If you print `str`, it starts printing at the `E`. If you print `str +2`, it will print "PA1". If you print `str + 4` (as you are here), it prints "1".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First lets break down the expression:

```
str + str[0] - str[3]
```

Plugging in the values of `str[0]` and `str[3]` we get:

```
str + 'E' - 'A'
```

Assuming characters are represented in ASCII, this is the same as:

```
str + 69 - 65
```

Now, we'll take a quick shortcut and assume this is the same as:

```
str + (69 - 65)
```

Which gives us:

```
str + 4
```

Which is a pointer to element index 4 of the array, namely the character `'1'`.  So `printf` starts reading from there, and that's what gets printed.

---

Now going back to that shortcut:

```
str + (69 - 65)
```

This is not how this actually gets calculated.  Addition and subtraction are of the same precedence level and group left to right, so it's really:

```
(str + 69) - 65
```

The first subexpression generates a pointer to index 69, however the string literal that `str` points to doesn't have that many elements.  Therefore, because we're creating a pointer more than 1 element past the end of the array, the code exhibits [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  You were "lucky" in this case that it worked as expected.

Comment: So actually, without the ASCII table I have no chance of solving this?

Comment: You could always `printf` the character value with `"%d"` and figure it out that way.

Comment: @eagle_master: There are at least two problems in the code. One, C implementations are not required to use ASCII nor are required to have sequential codes for the letters (the code for E is not necessarily five greater than the code for A). Two, the C standard does not guarantee that address arithmetic works if it exceeds array bounds.

Comment: So a bounds check that `strlen(str) > (str[0] - str[3])` would be prudent and using the non-shortcut method to ensure the resulting pointer arithmetic remains within the original string would help avoid bad things happening.

Comment: One question remains for me, do I have to look up the ASCII value only for characters or are there also ASCII values for integers(int) (which I guess that it is the case)? And can I do such a manipulation only with characters?

Comment: @eagle_master Both letters and digits have ASCII codes, as do punctuation marks.  The `1` in the string is not the number 1 but the character `'1'` whose ASCII code is 49.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this:

```
char *str = "ESPA1";
printf("%s", str + 4);
```

Ascii value of `'A'` is 65 and `'E'` is 69, thus subtraction gives 4 and you're referencing the `5th`  element from base `str` which is, of course, location/reference of the first element.

To know more about pointer arithmetic:

[Pointer Arithmetic](https://www.javatpoint.com/pointer-arithmetic-in-c)

[ASCII Table](https://www.ascii-code.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how do I know without the ASCII table, that these are the values for this example? Or is this even possible without the ASCII table?

Comment: ascii values are always same, yeah possible without ascii values, as said ascii value subtraction just give you the number/index here